# Doubt about proof of Fejer's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, fourier-analysis

$$f(t)= \frac{1 }{\pi n}\frac{sin^2(\frac{nt}{2})}{sin^2(\frac{t}{2})}$$

$f_n(t) \geq 0$

$\int_0^\pi$ $f_n(t )dt=1$

any $\delta>0$ $f_n(t)$ uniformly converges to $0$ when $t\in[\delta,\pi]$

Now book uses that $\int_\delta^\pi f_n(t)dt$ $\leq$ $\pi supf_n(t)$,
$\delta\leq t\leq\pi$

Maybe this is easy question but I am stuck from what argument this follows

Comment: Is there a comma missing? in $\pi \sup f_n(t) \delta $?

Comment: @FOE Yes.Thanks

Comment: Then you are just using $\int_a^b g(t) dt \leq (b-a) \sup_{(a,b)}g(t)$

Comment: @FOE Yes thank you. I understood after posting this, just forgot that formula when posting :)

Comment: No problem!....